# Service in @Effect() isn't called

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have a situation wherein the effect is called but the underlying service isn't accessed. What's causing it?

**user.effect.ts**

```js
@Effect()
getData$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(UserActions.getData),
    switchMap(() =>
        this.userService.getUserById(localStorage.getItem("uid")).pipe(
            map((data: IUser) => {
                if (data) {
                    return UserActions.dataReceived({
                        payload: UserService.parseData(data)
                    });
                } else {
                    return UserActions.dataNotReceived();
                }
            }),
            catchError(err =>
                of(
                    AuthActions.signOutError({
                        errorMessage: err.message,
                        errorCode: err.code
                    })
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**user.service.ts**

```js
getUserById(id) {
    this.logger.debug(`Getting user ${id}`);
    return this.afs
        .collection("users")
        .doc(id)
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
            map(action => {
                const data = action.payload.data();
                const uid = action.payload.id;
                return { uid, ...data };
            })
        );
}
```

Comment: How are you sure that effect is called?

Comment: I can see it logged out https://imgur.com/3asMkMx, but as you can see state is unchanged

Comment: Did you register effect in your module?

Comment: Yes, I have, it's registered.

Comment: And you're not seeing any errors?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors in the `console.log`

Comment: is the effect actually being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use return new not return. Like this

```
            if (data) {
                return new UserActions.dataReceived({
                    payload: UserService.parseData(data)
                });
            } else {
                return new UserActions.dataNotReceived();
            }
```